# Estimates of parameters of interest $θ_1$ & $θ_2$ ($\pm$ standard errors) were $25\pm10$ & $10\pm3$. Find estimate & Standard Error of $δ=θ_1/5−θ_2$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, estimation, standard-error

**Problem:**
In two independent studies, the estimates of the parameters of interest $θ_1$ and $θ_2$ ($\pm$ their standard errors) were computed to be $25\pm 10$ and $10\pm 3$, respectively. If one is interested in the difference $\delta =\dfrac{θ_1}5−θ_2$ of the two parameters, what would an estimate of $\delta$ and of its standard error be?

Comment: Obviously an exercise. Share first your thoughts!

Comment: Are the estimates independent (or at least uncorrelated)?